# AD credentials for ActiveMQ shared access

Tags: active-directory, activemq-classic, nas

I am trying to configure a shared ActiveMQ configuration over a NAS shared folder. However the shared folder needs AD credentials to access. How do I add these credentials in the ActiveMQ configuration file for it to access the NAS? Any other solution is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Shared folder mounting should be done at the OS or in a script before ActiveMQ starts. This sounds like an operational prerequisite that must be handled before ActiveMQ starts.

Side note-- you mentioned AD credentials-- be mindful that Windows file shares (CIFS/SMB) generally do not have reliable locking semantics and should not be used as a back-end for ActiveMQ server processes.

Comment: I am able to access the NAS on my server but i am not able to use it as a data store. Logs say failed to create the directory...

Comment: Would need to know the make and model of the NAS. What OS does it run, etc? Sounds like a permissions issue on the share and not an ActiveMQ issue. Share the logs of the error if you can.